# Ho to define Filter inside ServletInitializer by using url-mapping

Tags: spring, spring-security, servlet-filters

Old style via web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>accessFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.app.AccessFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>accessFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

How can I achieve the same via the initializer class:

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    //...

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() { // nice. thx. url-mapping?
        return new Filter[]{ new AccessFilter() };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this.

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
      FilterRegistration.Dynamic encodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("accessFilter", new AccessFilter());
      encodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/admin/*");

      super.onStartup(servletContext);
}
```